# "Seize the night" vs. "Enjoy the night"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I was listening to "We Own the Night", by "The Wanted" and I realized the phrase "we are only young if we seize the night".

*Seize*, in this case, sounds like *enjoy*, right? But, what's the contextual difference between them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Seize the night" comes from the Latin [*carpe noctem*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carpe_noctem) which is a pun of [*carpe diem*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carpe_diem) (seize the day).

It comes from:

> *Carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero*

Which means:

> "Seize the day while trusting little on what tomorrow might bring."

(From Horace, Odes I.xi.8)

It essentially means: Live today as if it's your last.

So, *seize the night*, in the context of the song, means: *Live (party) like it's your last night*.

Comment: Then can I use *seize* for everything that I want to transmit more emotional emphasis than just a simple *enjoy*?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge That's subjective and completely relies on the context. As stated that in the context of the song it means this. Literally is means to *own the night*, which could mean something as mundane as 'Finish all your homework in one night' or 'Watch all your favorite Dexter episodes tonight' if you put it into that context.

Comment: in other words, it's Latin for YOLO?

Comment: Tantum semel vivis

Comment: I like the following: carpe dial: seize the soap.  carpe carp: seize the fish

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge if you are familiar with Portuguese then perhaps it would be better to think of this as "aproveitar". For example "seize the day" (aproveite o dia) means take advantage of the day, but "seize the hotdog" (aproveitar o hotdog) doesn't really mean "enjoy the hotdog" in English.

Comment: @DanNeely No, Dan. No. Shame on you.

Answer (score 5):

*to seize*, to take possession of, to grab.. to convey the idea of *owning the night*, a figurative way to say to live the night fully, to get the best out of it.

Comment: But, seize shouldn't become seizure, like enjoy becomes enjoyment!

Answer (score 4):

**Seize** in this case is used for "embrace".  It implies more emotional energy than "enjoy"

Answer (score 4):

"Seize the night" is obviously a take on "Seize the day", which comes from the Latin expression "carpe diem". That is a well-known saying with a specific sense, so outside of that expression, you **cannot** generalize "seize" to any other meaning than "to take."

Answer (score 1):

"we are only young if we seize the night". Seize: to use legal or official power to take (something). In this instance it would be, we are only young if we take control of the night. Which probably accounts for the title of the song "We Own the Night".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between seize and enjoy is at least in part that to seize is to actively claim something or embrace it as one's own, whereas to enjoy can be passive, more on the order of just letting something happen. If you seize the night, you're behind the wheel and your foot is on the gas pedal; if you enjoy the night, you might only be along for the ride. To seize the night (or the day) is to declare an assertive intent to make the most of whatever is at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The band "twenty one pilots" lead singer had a tattoo that refers to carpe noctem, and means seize the night.  Seize the night means to overcome the world, overcome your troubles, and live everyday to its fullest.

Answer (score 0):

Carpe diem:  literal translation,  seize the day. Actual meaning, dont procrastinate.

Carpe noctem:  literal translation, seize the night. Actual meaning,  enjoy yourself like theres no tomorrow.

They didn't have a way to illuminate like we do so all the work needed to be done before nightfall. At night enjoying yourself was really all you could do unless you were rich.